# "If" statement doesn't work

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Why else doesn't work? And prints just "8" but doesn't "10". Where's mistake?

```
<% if controller.controller_name == ('home' || 'products') %>8<% else %>10<% end %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`||` operator returns first operand if it's not `nil` or `false`. Otherwise it returns second operand. So, in your case it's always returning 'home' and never 'products'.

You probably meant something like

```
<%= controller.controller_name.in?('home', 'products') ? 8 : 10 %>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple + 1 liner solution to your problem would be something like the following

```
if %w[home products].include? controller.controller_name
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `('home' || 'products')` will always return 'home'. `||` is an operation that always return the first non-nil and non-false statement. In this case, `'home'`. So your condition is exactly equal to `controller.controller == 'home'`.

What you are trying to do is:

```
<% if (controller.controller_name == 'home' || controller.controller_name == 'products') %>8<% else %>10<% end %>
```

Which will evaluate as you are imagining.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
case controller.controller_name
when "home" then 8
when "products" then 8
else 10
end
```

Comment: I didn't answer him, but rather proposed new solution, my mistake.